# Syncronized methods In MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter

Tags: java, red5

I am using red5 for mmo , and I am in trouble with syncronized methods , the methods which i used in MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter always blocking next request. Is it normal ? Because i am doing some database operations in these methods and this syncronized block is making my performance very poor. I decided to use quartz jobs to overcome this stuation, how ever this time clustered topolgy is making me confused . Could you please help me , is it a common solution to use quartz for this problem , is there any body to give me a smarter advice
Thank you

I want to make an addition to clear my question

After extending MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter   and create my overriden class , I implemented

```
public  boolean connect(IConnection conn, IScope scope, Object[] params) {
```

function and in this function I want to set user status Online (As you can see there is not any syncronized literal in this function however it is acting as there is.)
And I want to take user entity from database and then set online status and then save it back
In this part even if I dont use syncronized  literal , next coming client is waiting previous completed. I feel like I must create another job with Quartz and make database operations in that thread however I am not sure this decrease my performance. Is there any other way to prevent this block , this seems to be a Red5 limitation ??
This is also mentioned in a blog http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/red5-cabin-fever-advanced-scope-and-room-management/

Answer (score 0):

Only one thread can invoke synchronized method of an object, an quartz won't change it. And from your post doesn't seem what you want to achieve.